# how to debug my add-in under different environments in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've got an add-in, which can be embedded in different programs.

I'm sick of changing the path of external program in Properties.

I'd like to add a single project to the solution and choose the program in runtime, but there is a problem. External program is started in a new process with Process.Start so I can't debug it.

Is there another way to choose the external program in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, instead of adding your addin Release build, add the Debug build with its .pdb file.